# Checking for __debug__ and some other condition in Python

Tags: python, debugging, compilation

In Python sometimes I want to do something like (1)

```
if __debug__ and verbose: print "whatever"
```

If Python is run with -O, then I'd like for that whole piece of code to disappear, as it would if I just had (2)

```
if __debug__: print "whatever"
```

or even (3)

```
if __debug__:
    if verbose: print foo
```

However, that doesn't seem to happen (see below). Is there a way I can get the run-time efficiency of #3 with compact code more like #1?

Here's how I tested that I'm not getting the efficient code I want:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

from dis import dis
import sys

cmds = ["""
def func ():
    if __debug__ and 1+1: sys.stdout.write('spam')""",   """
def func():
    if __debug__: sys.stdout.write('ham')""",     """
def func():
    __debug__ and sys.stdout.write('eggs')"""]

print "__debug__ is", __debug__, "\n\n\n"

for cmd in cmds:
    print "*"*80, "\nSource of {}\n\ncompiles to:".format(cmd)
    exec(cmd)
    dis(func)
    print "\n"*4
```

Running this gives

```
__debug__ is False 



******************************************************************************** 
Source of 
def func ():
    if __debug__ and 1+1: sys.stdout.write('spam')

compiles to:
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (__debug__)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       31
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       31
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (sys)
             15 LOAD_ATTR                2 (stdout)
             18 LOAD_ATTR                3 (write)
             21 LOAD_CONST               2 ('spam')
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             27 POP_TOP             
             28 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 31)
        >>   31 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             34 RETURN_VALUE        





******************************************************************************** 
Source of 
def func():
    if __debug__: sys.stdout.write('ham')

compiles to:
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        





******************************************************************************** 
Source of 
def func():
    __debug__ and sys.stdout.write('eggs')

compiles to:
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (__debug__)
              3 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    21
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (sys)
              9 LOAD_ATTR                2 (stdout)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                3 (write)
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 ('eggs')
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
        >>   21 POP_TOP             
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Don't confuse runtime efficiency with code size. I can't imagine that the difference in time required to skip 9 instructions vs 5 instructions, as in your example, would even be detectable in any but the most contrived examples.

Comment: If this is really important (which it probably isn't), and writing (3) is really not acceptable, your best bet is to use something like [MacroPy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy).

Comment: My example above isn't great in that it can be handled by defining a function print_verbose that includes the if verbose: check. Also, I believe there's no way to put two 'if' statements on the same line, which would do the trick, although it might be objectionable for other reasons.

Comment: @user1717856: You're right that you can't put two `if` statements on the same line. But so what? You can always put the _body_ on the same line as the second `if` if the teletype you use for programming has a daily line quota or something.

Comment: @user1717856: Wait, were you responding to `MacroPy`, and assuming that it couldn't do anything that takes multiple lines or affects indentation or something? If so, click the link; it's real syntactic macros. What you want would be trivial. For that matter, if `verbose` is meant to be a constant that's unchanged after startup, you could even pretty easily optimize out the `if verbose:` cases by evaluating the flag at import time with `MacroPy`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't. Python's compiler is not nearly smart enough to detect in what cases it could remove the code block and `if` statement.

Python would have to do a whole lot of logic inference otherwise. Compare:

```
if __debug__ or verbose:
```

with

```
if __debug__ and verbose:
```

for example. Python would have to detect the difference between these two expressions at compile time; one can be optimised away, the other cannot.

Note that the difference in runtime between code with and without `if __debug__` statements is truly minute, everything else being equal. A small constant value test and jump is not anything to fuss about, really.

Comment: If you look at `compile.c`, you can see exactly where this is handled: in [`compiler_if`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Python/compile.c#l1841), if the if-expr is an always-false or always-true immutable constant, as determined by `expr_constant`, it doesn't compile the body or the or-else. And [`expr_constant`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Python/compile.c#l3186) treats `__debug__` as either always true or always false, depending on the value of `c_optimize`. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @abarnert: Yup, and as the comment states: *`__debug__` is not assignable*. Anything else in the expression *would* be assignable.

Comment: Of course, this being Python, there _are_ ways to assign the magic unassignable constants if you really want to write impossible-to-debug code. Not as many as there used to be, but even in 3.4, `builtins.__dict__['True'] = 0` works; `ellipsis` and literal strings and numbers are harder, but then using `if ...:` is probably already obfuscated enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this since Python 3.10+. As long as you keep the if condition from getting too complicated and put the check on `__debug__` first, the newer python versions behave as you'd want it to. Here's a modified version of the original code:

```py
from dis import dis
import sys

def func_debug_only(x):
    if __debug__:
        print('spam')

def func_debug_and_const(x):
    if __debug__ and True:
        print('spam')

def func_const_and_debug(x):
    if True and __debug__: # Using const int instead of True is identical
        print('spam')

def func_truth_and_debug(x):
    if 1==1 and __debug__: # -O doesn't remove this
        print('spam')

def func_debug_and_var(x):
    if __debug__ and x: # -O removes this
        print('spam')

def func_var_and_debug(x):
    # -O doesn't remove this; This makes sense as using x in the if
    # statement might trigger x.__bool__() or x.__len__() that might
    # have unpredictable (to the interpreter side effects). Even if
    # the if condition fails, order of condition evaluation would
    # mean that bool(x) is evaluated.
    if x and __debug__:
        print('spam')

def func_debug_nested(x):
    if __debug__:
        if x:
            print('spam')

def func_debug_nested2(x):
    if x: # Doesn't completely go away; 3.12 generates slightly smaller code than 3.10
        if __debug__:
            print('spam')

print("__debug__ is", __debug__, "on version", sys.version_info)
for fn in [func_debug_only, func_debug_and_const, func_const_and_debug, func_truth_and_debug, func_debug_and_var, func_var_and_debug, func_debug_nested, func_debug_nested2]:
    print('\n', fn.__name__)
    dis(fn)
```

This gives you:

```
__debug__ is False on version sys.version_info(major=3, minor=10, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

 func_debug_only
  5           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE

 func_debug_and_const
  9           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE

 func_const_and_debug
 13           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE

 func_truth_and_debug
 17           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        6 (to 12)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE

 func_debug_and_var
 21           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE

 func_var_and_debug
 25           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        4 (to 8)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
        >>    8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

 func_debug_nested
 29           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE

 func_debug_nested2
 34           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        4 (to 8)

 35           4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE

 34     >>    8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```